# restore first radio button checked onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I am a beginner of writing javascript, thank you for the patient here :)

I like to set my first radio button as checked as default. After checking on the 2nd/3rd/4th radio buttons, I like to click on the "click me" button and restore the first radio button as checked again. here is the html code

```js
function restoreRadio(){
document.getElementByClassName('radioButton').checked = "false";
document.querySelectorAll('radioButton:first-child').checked = "true"

}
```

```css
ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
marging: 0;
}

ul li{
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="tryout" class="radioButton" checked="checked">
 </li>
 
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="tryout" class="radioButton">
 </li>
 
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="tryout" class="radioButton">
 </li>
 
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="tryout" class="radioButton">
 </li>
</ul>

<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="restoreRadio()">
```

If you can please explain why the javascript did not work as intend so I can learn from it. Thank you once again for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have ".radioButton" (css query format) as your selector and set `checked` to `true` (use boolean not string). Because you just want one element, you should just use `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector('.radioButton:first-child').checked = true;
```

Comment: Change "getElementByClassName" to `getElementByClassName` and then iterate over the results to change each `element` to `checked=false`. I strongly recommend opening your console in Chrome's Developer Tools to check out some of these Javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Note the correct syntax is `getElementsByClassName` (plural).